# How to set up an intranet?

Tags: intranet

i want to setup a small intranet for a small company. 
I know how to setup apache for the internet, but not for the intranet.

I'm working in Ubuntu 12.04.
Is there a good resource for the perfect intranet ? :)

Comment: *Is there a good resource for the perfect intranet* - as "intranet" means different things to different people, and what's perfect for a small company isn't going to be what's perfect for Ford or Apple or Harvard University, the answer is somewhere between "no" and "define" what "perfect" and "intranet" mean to you and then we'll talk.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit open-ended. Some companies simply use a Wiki for intranet purposes. There are also collaboration suites like [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview) that work well. There's probably a corporate standard in [Microsoft's Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/capabilities/Pages/default.aspx).

See: [How to setup an Intranet site and a FREE alternative to Sharepoint](https://serverfault.com/questions/26397/how-to-setup-an-intranet-site-and-a-free-alternative-to-sharepoint)

But maybe you're asking about the mechanics of getting your systems to a local Apache installation. Do you have internal DNS in the environment? That would be a requirement so that the local computers can be directed to an internal site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really any different to a setup for an Internet site, except that you might want to have an `Allow from 192.168.0.0/24` (or whatever your subnet is).  Or restrict access to it with your office firewall.

Comment: Why the downvote?